# Sharepoint like Versioning in Dotnet aplication

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sharepoint, versioning

I want to achieve versioning for one of my Dotnet Application.

I like the way SharePoint has implemented versioning.

I would like versioning similar to SharePoint.

Can anyone guide on this?

Like if i have 10 columns in 1 sql table, say Student.

I have changed 2 columns- say RollNummber and ClassteacherName, remaining 8 are same.

So when i click on versioning, I should see only columns which have been changed.

I would like to store last 20 Versions.

Will it affect my DB?

Please advice.

Comment: Sharepoint has a restore function for versioning, do you want same function ?

Comment: No, I just need to know last values.

Comment: If you use EntityFramework write custom function for save and inside check modified column, with StringBuilder create a string with: "ColumnName: OldValue, NewValue; ColumnName: OldValue, NewValue" and save this info with tableName, userId, dateTime, etc on HistoryTable

Comment: Question here is, I have to add everything in one HostoryTable
or I Should have as many Historytable as my SQL DB has
or I should not change my table structure at all, Add one flag in each table(IsVersioned) and then have multiple records inserted for each edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion about History:

1. If main purpose is to **ONLY** log (No restore) changed fields my advice is to store all on HystoryTable with Date,User,etc and finally a Varchar(MAX) with all Fields changed with OldValue and NewValue (maybe with a special charter between fields to better parse string for display)

   - **Pro**

     - All info one table
     - Simple clean
     - Do not "damage" real data
     - Simply implementation
   - **Cons**

     - Not simple restore data (consider relations)

2. If main purpose is **ALSO** restore, you can

   #### Log changed data inside same table with a FlagDelete or instead of update rec, insert a new one and mark the actual with a DateTime on specific column.

   - **Pro**

     - Relative simple Restore
   - **Cons**

     - You have mixed data (History Data and Actual Data) every query must specify what kind of data do you want (error prone)
     - Table must contains a large percentage of unused data, this impact query performance.

     #### Log Changed data to "Ghost" Table with same structure of original.
   - **Pro**

     - At first glance restore seem to be simple but you have to fight with relations (different
       tables)
     - Separation between actual data and History data
   - **Cons**

     - You have to consider relations,
     - You have to sync table structure and consider relations (foreign keys)
     - Many tables

Your choice

Comment: Thanks @Max, I will go with option 1.